# deadlock c++ thread condition variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, deadlock

I have a problem with a class called Workers.

```
Workers::Workers(int _nbThreads):
  goWork(false),
  progressWork(false),
  endWork(false),
  endFinishedWork(false),
  nbThreads(_nbThreads)
{

  for(int i=0;i<nbThreads;i++){ 
    threads.push_back(new std::thread(&Workers::threadsExecute,this,i));
  }
}

void Workers::threadsExecute(int numThread){
  for(;;){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uniqueMutexWork(mutexWork);
    conditionWorkStarted.wait(uniqueMutexWork, [this] {return goWork==true;});
    progressWork=true;
    mutexWork.unlock();
    conditionWorkProgress.notify_all();
    for(;!endWork;);
    mutexWork.lock();
    endFinishedWork=true;
    mutexWork.unlock();
    conditionWorkFinished.notify_all();
    break;

  }
}

void Workers::threadsEnd(){
  for(int i=0;i<nbThreads;i++){ 
    threads[i]->join();
  }
}



void Workers::startWork(int numThread){
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uniqueMutexWork(mutexWork);
  goWork=true;
  conditionWorkStarted.notify_all();
  conditionWorkProgress.wait(uniqueMutexWork, [this] {return progressWork==true;});  
}

void Workers::stopWork(int numThread){
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uniqueMutexWork(mutexWork);
  endWork=true;
  conditionWorkFinished.wait(uniqueMutexWork, [this] {return endFinishedWork==true;});   
}
```

The main :

```
Workers workers* = new Workers(1);//Only one thread worker
workers->startWork(0);
workers->stopWork(0);
```

The problem is that the variable endWork is never found to true in

```
for(;!endWork;);
```

However, this one is well put to true in the stopWork method :

```
endWork=true;
```

If I replace

```
  for(;!endWork;);
```

by

```
for(;!endWork;){printf("work\n");}
```

The program works well !
What is my error ?

I look forward to your response.

Comment: Your problem is that you've done nothing to tell the compiler that `EndWork` may be modified by another thread, nor synchronised access to it.   The compiler can therefore assume, within `threadsExecute()` that `EndWork` never changes, and optimise accordingly.   Putting a `printf()` introduces the possibility that some other code changes it (i.e. you get lucky by doing that).    The better approach would be to protect access to `EndWork` using `mutexWork`, or somehow ensure access to `EndWork` is atomic in all threads.

Comment: Yes, when a compile with -O3, the program don't works, but with -O2, the program works well ! But it is surprising that the compiler done that. Thanks!

Comment: @Nicholas - it is not at all surprising that the compiler "done that".   What you describe is typical, since your code did not take any needed precautions to synchronise access to a variable when one thread is modifying its value and another thread is accessing its value.

Comment: Can you give more details about what you want to do with your code? Start threads, interrupt it if needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `for(;!endWork;){printf("work\n");}` The program works well ! What is my error ?

Since the variable `endWork` is a regular variable, compiler with high optimization option (i.e. `-O3`) might assume the variable does not change and optimize out the read inside the loop, i.e. it transforms the loop:

```
for( ; !endWork; ) ;
```

to

```
if(!endWork) for (;;) ;
```

With `printf()` there are too many things going on, so the compiler cannot figure out if we change `endWork` variable inside the `printf()`. So, it does not optimize the loop as shown above.

How to deal with the issue? The simplest would be to declare `endWork` as volatile. This will give compilation a hint, that the value `endWork` might be changed elsewhere (i.e. by another thread), so it will not optimize the loop as showed above.